# How to generate background colors for div's based on the value rendered from an json object.-javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like below:

[image]

I'm trying to create 10 `divs` for every key(i.e:'publicExploit,activeAttacks..etc) in the object shown and set the background color of every `div` depending on the value, i.e

- 0: grey
- 1: yellow
- 2-4: orange
- 5+: red

here is the code:

```
items: [
  this.info = new Ext.BoxComponent({
    tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
      '<div class="vuln-summary-status-item">',
      '<div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">text1{[this.getEasyExploit(values)]}</div>',
      '<div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">text2{[this.getDenialOfService(values)]}</div>',
      '<div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">text3{[this.getExploitKit(values)]}</div>',
      '<div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">text4{[this.getMalware(values)]}</div>',
      '<div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">text5{[this.getHighDataLoss(values)]}</div>',
      '<div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">text6{[this.getHighLateralMovement(values)]}</div>',
      '<div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">text7{[this.getActiveAttacks(values)]}</div>',
      '</div>', {


        getEasyExploit: function(value) {
          if (value.easyExploit === 0) {
            return '<div class="greyColor">' + value.easyExploit + '</div>'
          } else if (value.easyExploit === 1) {
            return '<div class="yellowColor">' + value.easyExploit + '</div>'
          } else if (value.easyExploit === 2 || value.easyExploit === 3 || value.easyExploit === 4) {
            return '<div class="orangeColor">' + value.easyExploit + '</div>'
          } else if (value.easyExploit >= 5) {
            return '<div class="redColor">' + value.easyExploit + '</div>'
          }
        },
        getDenialOfService: function(value) {
          if (value.denialOfService === 0) {
            return '<div class="greyColor">' + value.denialOfService + '</div>'
          } else if (value.denialOfService === 1) {
            return '<div class="yellowColor">' + value.denialOfService + '</div>'
          } else if (value.denialOfService === 2 || value.denialOfService === 3 || value.denialOfService === 4) {
            return '<div class="orangeColor">' + value.denialOfService + '</div>'
          } else if (value.denialOfService >= 5) {
            return '<div class="redColor">' + value.denialOfService + '</div>'
          }
        },
        getExploitKit: function(value) {
          if (value.exploitKit === 0) {
            return '<div class="greyColor">' + value.exploitKit + '</div>'
          } else if (value.exploitKit === 1) {
            return '<div class="yellowColor">' + value.exploitKit + '</div>'
          } else if (value.exploitKit === 2 || value.exploitKit === 3 || value.exploitKit === 4) {
            return '<div class="orangeColor">' + value.exploitKit + '</div>'
          } else if (value.exploitKit >= 5) {
            return '<div class="redColor">' + value.exploitKit + '</div>'
          }
        },
        getMalware: function(value) {
          if (value.malware === 0) {
            return '<div class="greyColor">' + value.malware + '</div>'
          } else if (value.malware === 1) {
            return '<div class="yellowColor">' + value.malware + '</div>'
          } else if (value.malware === 2 || value.malware === 3 || value.malware === 4) {
            return '<div class="orangeColor">' + value.malware + '</div>'
          } else if (value.malware >= 5) {
            return '<div class="redColor">' + value.malware + '</div>'
          }

        },
        getHighDataLoss: function(value) {
          if (value.highDataLoss === 0) {
            return '<div class="greyColor">' + value.highDataLoss + '</div>'
          } else if (value.highDataLoss === 1) {
            return '<div class="yellowColor">' + value.highDataLoss + '</div>'
          } else if (value.highDataLoss === 2 || value.highDataLoss === 3 || value.highDataLoss === 4) {
            return '<div class="orangeColor">' + value.highDataLoss + '</div>'
          } else if (value.highDataLoss >= 5) {
            return '<div class="redColor">' + value.highDataLoss + '</div>'
          }
        },
        getHighLateralMovement: function(value) {
          if (value.highLateralMovement === 0) {
            return '<div class="greyColor">' + value.highLateralMovement + '</div>'
          } else if (value.highLateralMovement === 1) {
            return '<div class="yellowColor">' + value.highLateralMovement + '</div>'
          } else if (value.highLateralMovement === 2 || value.highLateralMovement === 3 || value.highLateralMovement === 4) {
            return '<div class="orangeColor">' + value.highLateralMovement + '</div>'
          } else if (value.highLateralMovement >= 5) {
            return '<div class="redColor">' + value.highLateralMovement + '</div>'
          }
        },

        getActiveAttacks: function(value) {
          if (value.activeAttacks === 0) {
            return '<div class="greyColor">' + value.activeAttacks + '</div>'
          } else if (value.activeAttacks === 1) {
            return '<div class="yellowColor">' + value.activeAttacks + '</div>'
          } else if (value.activeAttacks === 2 || value.activeAttacks === 3 || value.activeAttacks === 4) {
            return '<div class="orangeColor">' + value.activeAttacks + '</div>'
          } else if (value.activeAttacks >= 5) {
            return '<div class="redColor">' + value.activeAttacks + '</div>'
          }
        },

      }
    )
  })
]
```

the css looks:

```
.greyColor {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  height: 120px;
}

.yellowColor {
  background: rgb(255, 198, 55);
  height: 120px;
}

.orangeColor: {
  background: rgb(229, 108, 25);
  height: 120px;
}

.redColor: {
  background: rgb(222, 29, 11);
  height: 120px;
}
```

I have 2 issues:

1. I feel that my way writing the code is too sloppy, Is there any better of writing the code for generating div depending on the value associated with it?
2. I'm not able to get the condition right for `else if(value.denialOfService === 2 || value.denialOfService === 3 || value.denialOfService === 4)`
   here I'm trying to set the `div` background whose values are between 2-4, but does not render properly.

Any clue how this could be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one will let you pass a text value to be rendered.

```
items: [
  this.info = new Ext.BoxComponent({
    tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
      '<div class="vuln-summary-status-item">',
      '    <div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">{[this.getColorDiv(values.easyExploit, "Easy Exploit")]}</div>',
      '    <div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">{[this.getColorDiv(values.denialOfService, "Denial Of Service")]}</div>',
      '    <div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">{[this.getColorDiv(values.exploitKit, "Exploit Kit")]}</div>',
      '    <div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">{[this.getColorDiv(values.malware, "Malware")]}</div>',
      '    <div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">{[this.getColorDiv(values.highDataLoss, "High Data Loss")]}</div>',
      '    <div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">{[this.getColorDiv(values.highLateralMovement, "High Lateral Movement")]}</div>',
      '    <div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">{[this.getColorDiv(values.activeAttacks, "Active Attacks")]}</div>',
      '</div>', {
        colors: [
          'greyColor',
          'yellowColor',
          'orangeColor',
          'redColor'
        ],
        getColor(value) {
          switch(true) {
            case value < 2:
              return colors[value];
              break;
            case value < 5:
              return colors[2];
              break;
            default:
              return colors[4];
              break;
          } 
        },
        getColorDiv: function(value, text) {
          return '<div class="'+ this.getColor(value).+'">' + text + ": " + value + '</div>';
        }
      }
    )
  })
]
```

## Original

It would be easier to utilize a color array, which would let you combine your functions.

```
items: [
  this.info = new Ext.BoxComponent({
    tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
      '<div class="vuln-summary-status-item">',
      '    <div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">{[this.getColorDiv(values.easyExploit)]}</div>',
      '    <div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">{[this.getColorDiv(values.denialOfService)]}</div>',
      '    <div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">{[this.getColorDiv(values.exploitKit)]}</div>',
      '    <div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">{[this.getColorDiv(values.malware)]}</div>',
      '    <div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">{[this.getColorDiv(values.highDataLoss)]}</div>',
      '    <div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">{[this.getColorDiv(values.highLateralMovement)]}</div>',
      '    <div class="vuln-summary-status-item-inner">{[this.getColorDiv(values.activeAttacks)]}</div>',
      '</div>', {
        colors: [
          'greyColor',
          'yellowColor',
          'orangeColor',
          'redColor'
        ],
        getColor(value) {
          switch(true) {
            case value < 2:
              return colors[value];
              break;
            case value < 5:
              return colors[2];
              break;
            default:
              return colors[4];
              break;
          } 
        },
        getColorDiv: function(value) {
          return '<div class="'+ this.getColor(value).+'">' + value + '</div>';
        }
      }
    )
  })
]
```

Comment: the value that i get as an argument for the "getColorDiv" is an object(shown above) and not the actual value (i.e: 0, 1,2..) Is there nay way to tweak this to have it compare with the actual value rendered..?\

Comment: in your question you're passing `values` as an object. in mine I have `this.getColorDiv(values.easyExploit)` which uses the object and passes the value directly.

sorry, hit Enter early.

you just need to pass the value of 1-5+ from each object to the "get Color Div" to have the function work.

Comment: No problem. Glad to hear it worked. Good luck with your app.

Comment: actually one more help int his regards, I have been wanting to display the text as well with the count(edited above in the question). However as of now the text renders above the colored div, is there any way I could render that inside that div..?

Comment: yeah add an argument to getcolorDiv which lets you pass a text value.